# Jenkins CI: how to trigger build on special svn comment

Tags: svn, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How I can trigger Jenkins to build project by special string in comment of commit?

For example, I want to publish project to Beta env. only when I put "Beta build" string in comment of svn commit.

Comment: You question asks a specific part of an envisioned implementation for the problem you are having. Perhaps if you state the full problem you are trying to solve, you might find out another plugin (e.g. Promoted Builds Plugin) will solve it better.  (Promoted Builds allows you to "promote" a specific build.  I use it so publish executables that are ready to be consumed by other users.)

Comment: In the advanced part of the subversion configuration in a job you have "Excluded Commit Messages". Try to match the message not containing your string `^((?!string).)*$` -- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the advanced part of the subversion configuration in a job you have "Excluded Commit Messages". Try to match the message not containing your string ^((?!string).)*$ -- see [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word)